# Need to make a slider working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello every one i need your help buddies. I am using this code of js to make it work.

but i dont want to add an external js in it...

```js
"use strict";
var $ = window.jQuery;

/*
var BEDROOM_RATES = {
 b1 : 119,
 b2 : 139,
 b3 : 159,
 b4 : 189,
 b5 : 219,
 b6 : 249
};
*/
var BEDROOM_RATES = {
 b1 : 99,
 b2 : 119,
 b3 : 139,
 b4 : 169,
 b5 : 189,
 b6 : 229
};
var PER_BATHROOM = 20;

$(window).ready(function() {
 updatePrice();
 $('input[type=radio]').on('change', updatePrice);
 $('#ui-slider1, #ui-slider2').on('slidechange', updatePrice);
 
}); // doc ready



function updatePrice() {
 var perc_off = 0.0,
   bedrooms = $('#ui-slider1').slider('option', 'value'),
   bathrooms = $('#ui-slider2').slider('option', 'value'),
   freq_id = $('input[type=radio]:checked').attr('id'),
   total_price = 0;
  
  total_price = BEDROOM_RATES['b'+bedrooms];
  total_price += bathrooms * PER_BATHROOM;
  
  if (freq_id == 'r1') {
   // one time
   perc_off = 0;
   
  }
  else if (freq_id == 'r2') {
   // weekly 20% off
   perc_off = .20;
   
  }
  else if (freq_id == 'r3') {
   // bi-weekly 15% off
   perc_off = .15;
  }
  else if ((freq_id == 'r4') || (freq_id == 'r5')) {
   // every 3 or 4 weeks, 10% off
   perc_off = .1;
  }
  
  // subtract frequency discount
  total_price *= (1-perc_off);
  // set total price on button
  $("#total-price").html(parseInt(total_price));
}


$(document).on('change', '#ui-slider__amount1', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});

$(document).on('submit', '#home-form', function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    var $_form = $(this);
    var $_service_id = $('#service_id');
    var bedrooms = $('#ui-slider__amount1').val();
    var bathrooms = $('#ui-slider__amount2').val();

 $('#input-bedrooms').val(bedrooms);
 $('#input-bathrooms').val(bathrooms);
    $('#pricing_parameter_qty').val(bathrooms);
    
    if (bedrooms == 1) {
        $_service_id.val(4);
    }
    else if (bedrooms == 2) {
        $_service_id.val(6);
    }
    else if (bedrooms == 3) {
        $_service_id.val(2);
    }
    else if (bedrooms == 4) {
        $_service_id.val(1);
    }
    else if (bedrooms == 5) {
        $_service_id.val(3);
    }
    else if (bedrooms == 6) {
        $_service_id.val(7);
    }
    else {
        $_service_id.val(4);
    }
});


This is external java script
```

```css
Check demo working on 
http://getondesk.com/demo/zenclean/

Its a front slider
```

```html
<form id="home-form" action="guestbook.php" method="get">
      <input id="input-bedrooms" name="bedrooms" value="1" type="hidden">
      <input id="input-bathrooms" name="bathrooms" value="1" type="hidden">
      <div class="flag flag--small mb pb--">
     <div class="flag__img">
       <p class="slider-result-wrap">Bedrooms: <input value="1" id="ui-slider__amount1" class="slider-result" type="text"></p>
       <input id="service_id" name="service_id" value="4" type="hidden">
     
     </div>
     <div class="flag__body">
       <div class="ui-slider-wrap">
      <div class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-slider1" data-max="6"><div style="width: 0%;" class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-slider-range-min"></div><span style="left: 0%;" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0"></span></div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flag flag--small mb">
     <div class="flag__img">
       <p class="slider-result-wrap">Bathrooms: <input value="1" id="ui-slider__amount2" class="slider-result" type="text"></p>
       <input name="pricing_parameters[pricing_parameter_id]" value="1" type="hidden">
       <input id="pricing_parameter_qty" name="pricing_parameters[quantity]" value="1" type="hidden">
     </div>
     <div class="flag__body">
       <div class="ui-slider-wrap">
      <div class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-slider2" data-max="6"><div style="width: 0%;" class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-slider-range-min"></div><span style="left: 0%;" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0"></span></div>
       </div>
     </div>
      </div>

      <div class="layout layout--top layout--small">
     <div class="layout__item large-and-up-1/4 1/2">
       <div class="radio_wrap">
      <input id="r1" name="frequency_id" value="10" class="styled-radiobutton--text" type="radio">
      <label for="r1" class="radio"><div class="verticalize">1 time service</div></label>
      <p></p>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="layout__item large-and-up-1/4 1/2">
       <div class="radio_wrap">
      <input id="r2" name="frequency_id" value="20" class="styled-radiobutton--text" type="radio">
      <label for="r2" class="radio"><div class="verticalize">Every week</div></label>
      <p>20% Off</p>
       </div>

     </div>

     <div class="layout__item large-and-up-1/4 1/2">
       <div class="radio_wrap">
      <input id="r3" name="frequency_id" value="30" class="styled-radiobutton--text perc" checked="checked" type="radio">
      <label for="r3" class="radio"><div class="verticalize">Every 2 weeks <span>(Most popular)</span></div></label>
      <p>15% Off</p>
       </div>

     </div>
     <!--
     <div class="layout__item large-and-up-1/4 1/2">
       <div class="radio_wrap">
      <input type="radio" id="r4" name="frequency_id" value="20" class="styled-radiobutton--text" />
      <label for="r4" class='radio'><div class="verticalize">Every 3 weeks</div></label>
      <p>10% Off</p>
       </div>

     </div>
     -->
     <div class="layout__item large-and-up-1/4 1/2">
       <div class="radio_wrap">
      <input id="r5" name="frequency_id" value="40" class="styled-radiobutton--text" type="radio">
      <label for="r5" class="radio"><div class="verticalize">Every 4 weeks</div></label>
      <p>10% Off</p>
       </div>
     </div>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center pt">
     <button id="book-appt" type="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn--large">BOOK NOW $<span id="total-price">101</span>/clean</button>
      </div>

   </form>
```

I dont want to use external js file without external js i need to make it run with datatype.

please help me in it. friends.

Comment: When you say "external JS file," do you mean a file from a different server?

Comment: No means we link a file but we dont want to link a file. from js folder

Comment: The file doesn't have to be in a specific folder. You just need to specify the correct path to it... unless you're using a framework that expects files to be in certain places.

Comment: then copy entire code of slider plugin and paste it inside `<script>` tag present in your `<head>` tag of your HTML page which is having these sliders. Thats very simple...:)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made One: Plz like it, it took 30min of my life xD. [Code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yegaVo). Take a look in FULL SCREEN MODE :

```js
var room = document.getElementById("bedNumber").getContext("2d");
var stay = document.getElementById("stayNumber").getContext("2d");

room.beginPath();
room.fillStyle = "red";
room.fillRect(20, 0, 30, 10);

stay.beginPath();
stay.fillStyle = "red";
stay.fillRect(20, 0, 30, 10);

var RoomNumber = 0;
var StayNumber = 0;
var Lux = 0;

function chose(context, event) {
  var X = event.clientX - 80;
  if (context == "room") {
    room.beginPath();
    room.fillStyle = "red";
    room.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 50);
    room.fillRect(X, 0, 30, 10);
    RoomNumber = X / 2;
  } else {
    stay.beginPath();
    stay.fillStyle = "red";
    stay.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 50);
    stay.fillRect(X, 0, 30, 10);
    StayNumber = X;
  }
  Price();
}

function addLuxury(lux) {
  Lux = lux * 50;
  Price();
}

function Price() {
  var Total = RoomNumber + StayNumber + Lux;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "BUY ROOM(S) FOR " + Total + "$";
}
```

```css
#slider {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
u {
  color: white;
}
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
button {
  background-color: #0099ff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 8px;
}
#total {
  background-color: #6666ff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="slider">
    <u><h1>Hotel Rooms For Good Price</h1></u>
    <br/>ROOMS :
    <canvas id="bedNumber" width="500" height="10" onclick="chose('room', event)"></canvas>
    <br/>
    <br/>STAY :
    <canvas id="stayNumber" width="500" height="10" onclick="chose('stay', event)"></canvas>
    <br/>
    <u><h3>Luxury</h3></u>
    <button onclick="addLuxury(0)">LUXURARY : BAD
      <br/>+0$ per/D</button>
    <button onclick="addLuxury(1)">LUXURARY : OK
      <br/>+75$ per/D</button>
    <button onclick="addLuxury(2)">LUXURARY : WOW
      <br/>+150$ per/D</button>
    <button onclick="addLuxury(3)">LUXURARY : BEST
      <br/>+215$ per/D</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button id="total">BUY ROOM(S) FOR 0$</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can u add it some where else i cant open code snipet